# sql natural join and cross join should give same output

Tags: sql, oracle

We're currently starting SQL in school ... so I'm very beginner.

Now we got a task that says:

```
Write a SQL-query which gives the same output like the following query. Use cross joins.

SELECT PRODUCT_NAME, QUANTITY_ON_HAND, WAREHOUSE_NAME
FROM WAREHOUSES
    NATURAL JOIN INVENTORIES
    NATURAL JOIN PRODUCT_INFORMATION
ORDER BY PRODUCT_NAME;
```

Now I don't know what to do. For me it doesn't make sense to replace natural join by cross join or isn't even possible?!

Please help.

Diagram:
[image: Diagram]

Comment: They are not same so you are right. Pls understand basics of join - 1. normal join natural join will produce records that exists in both table 2. left/right outer join - will produce all data from left/right table + matching from right/left table 3. cross join  will give left multiplied by right records 4. full join will produce matching + remaining in left + remaining in right table.

Comment: It is really sad that you are learning the so-called "natural" join if you are learning SQL.  It is just a very bad construct, because you don't see the `join` conditions.  The purpose of this exercise is even more obscene, because it is asking you to put `join` conditions in a `where` clause.  Sad, sad class.  I'm sorry you re being exposed to such bad practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cross join can be seen also as a **cartesian product**: so every row of the first table is combined with a row on the second one, so the resulting number of rows will be rows(TableA) * rows(TableB). 
To emulate a natural join with a cross join you'll need to compare the foreign/primary key of the different tables to see if they are the same like this:

```
SELECT PRODUCT_NAME, QUANTITY_ON_HAND, WAREHOUSE_NAME
FROM WAREHOUSES
    CROSS JOIN INVENTORIES
    CROSS JOIN PRODUCT_INFORMATION
WHERE WAREHOUSES.WAREHOUSES_ID = INVENTORIES.WAREHOUSE_ID AND
      INVENTORIES.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCT_INFORMATION.PRODUCT_ID
ORDER BY PRODUCT_NAME;
```

If you need more information about [cross-join](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php) or [natural join](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/natural-join.php).
If it can help you try to think at it like this:

- First you create a table with all the possible combination of rows
  between the three tables
- Than you start compare on each row the common and repetitive field, you've on each row 2 `PRODUCT_ID` and `WAREHOUSE_ID` columns, each of them coming from his specific table (try to execute the query taking all the columns with `*` to see this).
- After that you take only the rows where the 2 type of columns have the same value **(Emulating a natural join)**

You're just doing a normal join....with extra steps.